# shell shell scripting with oracle

Tags: shell-script, variable, here-document, sql

I am trying to substitute a unix variable to a select statement, but I am getting the below error. What did I do wrong?

```
sqlplus  "/ as sysdba" << EOF
spool /home/oracle/l.log

archive log list;
exit;
EOF

Adest=`cat  /home/oracle/l.log |head -4|tail -1|awk '{print $3}`
sqlplus "/ as sysdba" << EOF
spool /home/oracle/register.lst
select 'alter database register logfile '||''''||$Adest||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||'''' from v\$archived_log where applied='NO';
@ /home/oracle/register.lst
exit;
EOF

Error Log:-
SQL> select 'alter database register logfile '||''''||||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||'''' from v$archived_log where applied='NO';
select 'alter database register logfile '||''''||||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||'''' from v$archived_log where applied='NO'
                                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression 


SQL> @ /home/oracle/register.lst
SQL> exit;


cat  /home/oracle/l.log|head -4|tail -1|awk {'print $3'}
/u01/app/oracle/DG1_ARCH
```

Comment: 1) `cat spool /home/oracle/l.log|head -3|tail -1|awk '{print $3}` can be replace by  `awk 'NR==3 { print $3} '  spool /home/oracle/l.log`

Comment: 2) have you check `$Adest` is set ? `echo $Adest` before calling sql ?

Comment: yes i have added new script

Comment: This is the value i want to store in this varaible Adest [oracle@hpdba ~]$ cat  /home/oracle/l.log|head -4|tail -1|awk {'print $3'}
/u01/app/oracle/DG1_ARCH

Comment: replace `sqlplus "/ as sysdba"` by `cat`, does the value for `$Adest` is set ? if no, try `Adest=$( ... )` instead of backquote.

Comment: now i am getting the value but the sql statement having issue now

Comment: SQL> select 'alter database register logfile ''''||/u01/app/oracle/DG1_ARCH||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||''' from v\$archived_log where applied='NO'
                                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after adding the below

select 'alter database register logfile '''||'$Adest'||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||''';' from v\$archived_log where applied='NO';

Thanks for your suggestion and help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help below is working fine.

```
select 'alter database register logfile '''||'$Adest'||'/1_'||sequence#||'_915925946.dbf'||''';' from v\$archived_log where applied='NO';  

SQL> 
alter database register logfile '/u01/app/oracle/DG1_ARCH/1_452_915925946.dbf';
alter database register logfile '/u01/app/oracle/DG1_ARCH/1_453_915925946.dbf';
```